# Use WMIC to get a process' window title

Tags: wmic

I was using WMIC, and I saw this:

```
wmic process list brief find "spotify.exe"
```

- which should find a specific process, and return it's title, but I got an invalid list expression issue.

Anyone know what I could do instead? If preferable I would still like to use WMIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like this way with command line :

And add this switch `/I` means : Case-insensitive search.

---

```
wmic process list brief | findstr /I "spotify.exe"
```

Comment: I get this: FIND: Parameter format not correct

Comment: What's your OS ? and did you add the pipline `|` before the `find` command

Comment: Im using Windows 10 with PowerShell. Yes I did.

Comment: Try with cmd otherwise you can try this `wmic process list brief | findstr "spotify.exe"`

Comment: Thanks, it just gives me a blank string though

Comment: Because Spotify.exe is not running ; so try with `explorer.exe` like this way : `wmic process list brief | findstr "explorer.exe"`

Comment: It was running.

Comment: Oh haha, spotify with a capital S.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232547/discussion-between-hackoo-and-salvage-dev).